# WCF CommunicationException: understanding the root cause

Tags: wcf, communicationexception

I am writing an application that connects to the WCF service.
When I receive CommunicationException on the client side I need to understand whether the problem is on the service side or due to the invalid client configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following section to your WCF host config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="logs\WCFLog.svclog"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

this will create an svclog file which can give you more information about the cause of the connection problem.

Comment: But I need to determine the cause of the fault in the code immediately after the exception is received.

Comment: Could you give more information about the CommunicationException that you get? stacktrace, inner exception etc.